# How to retrieve similar values inside of objects in List of similar objects and create a map based on the values

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have a class named People

```
public class People{
       private String name;
       private String email;
       private String accountnum;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAccountnum() {
    return accountnum;
}

public void setAccountnum(String accountnum) {
    this.accountnum= accountnum;
}

public People(String name, String email, String accountnum) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.accountnum= accountnum;
}
```

}

I have a ArrayList of objects that created from this class

```
People peop1 = new People("john", "john@gmail.com", "56hk");
People peop2 = new People("Rose", "rose@gmail.com", "5689hk");
People peop3 = new People("john", "john@gmail.com", "5676hk");
People peop4 = new People("Rose", "rose@gmail.com", "6799hk");
People peop5 = new People("Jack", "jack@gmail.com", "7009hk");


List<People> peoplelist = new ArrayList<People>();

peoplelist .add(peop1);
peoplelist.add(peop2 );
peoplelist .add(peop3 );
```

What i want to do is to retrieve the email and its accountnums. 
like this

```
john@gmail.com = {56hk,5676hk};
rose@gmail.com = {5689hk,6799hk};
jack@gmail.com = {7009hk}
```

I know i can loop through and  return a map or use java streams and collection framework. But I don't know how to do it.

I tried to find similar solution but couldn't find any sorry if this is already asked.

Are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The collect all different accountnums of each person, you could use a `HashSet`. It would automatically eliminate duplicate values.

To collect the data of all persons, you could use a `HashMap` with email address as the key and the set of accountnums as the value.

Example:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create example input data
        List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
        peopleList.add(new People("john", "john@gmail.com", "56hk"));
        peopleList.add(new People("Rose", "rose@gmail.com", "5689hk"));
        peopleList.add(new People("john", "john@gmail.com", "5676hk"));
        peopleList.add(new People("Rose", "rose@gmail.com", "6799hk"));
        peopleList.add(new People("Jack", "jack@gmail.com", "7009hk"));

        // To collect the result. key=email, value=set of accountnum
        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        // Iterate over the input
        for (People person : peopleList)
        {
            // Get the existing data for the email address of this person
            Set<String> acountNumbers = map.get(person.getEmail());

            // If this is the first record for the email...
            if (acountNumbers == null)
            {
                // Create a new HashSet to collect the account numbers for this email
                acountNumbers = new HashSet<String>();
                acountNumbers.add(person.getAccountnum());
                map.put(person.getEmail(), acountNumbers);
            }
            else
            {
                // Add the accountnum to the existing set of account numbers
                acountNumbers.add(person.getAccountnum());
            }
        }

        // Output the result
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            String email = entry.getKey();
            Set<String> acountNumbers = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(email + " = " + acountNumbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
rose@gmail.com = [5689hk, 6799hk]
john@gmail.com = [5676hk, 56hk]
jack@gmail.com = [7009hk]
```